# Can an injectee know its own InjectionPoint?

Tags: java, ejb, cdi

Is there any way an injectee(EJB, say) know its own injection point?

```java
@Stateless
public class SomeService {

    @PostConstruct
    private void constructed() {
        // do post construction job
        // according to the injectionPoint
    }

    @Context
    private InjectionPoint injectionPoint; // is this possible?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are injecting your EJB with CDI (using `@Inject`) and if it has the default scope (no explicit scope or `@Dependent`).

You can inject its injection point:

```java
@Stateless
public class SomeService {

    @PostConstruct
    private void constructed() {
        // do post construction job
        // according to the injectionPoint
    }

    @Inject
    private InjectionPoint injectionPoint; // this is possible
}
```

Comment: @AntoineSabotDurand You got a new question. Thanks.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/32909962/330457