# How can I inject two EJBs of same type?

Tags: ejb, cdi

I'm trying to inject two EJBs of same type with different annotation.
But the instances injected are same.

```
@Path("/some")
public class SomeResource {

    @Inject
    @SomePostConstructionAnnotationForSomeService("this")
    private SomeService s1;

    @Inject
    @SomePostConstructionAnnotationForSomeService("that")
    private SomeService s2;
}
```

SomeService class looks like this.

```
public SomeService {

    @PostConstruct
    private void constructed() {
        // find the annotation and do something else.
    }

    @Inject
    private InjectionPoint injectionPoint;
}
```

The problem is that only `s1` is invoked and `s2` is equals `s1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if `SomeService` is `CDI` bean and its scope is `@Dependent` or no scope (that also means `@Dependent` when injected into another bean). What scope does it have? If `SomeService` is `EJB` bean not `CDI` this won't work.

**UPDATE:** 
You could move SomeService to a base class and create two different EJB beans by extending this class and inject these EJBs.

Comment: Oh, `SomeService` is an EJB.

Comment: You could move `SomeService` to a base class and create two different EJB beans by extending this class and inject these EJBs. Probably an interface will be also required - this should be checked.

Comment: Could you please move the last comment into the answer? It is a nice solution, but it took me a while to understand why the answer was accepted ... thanks

Comment: @A.Panzer it will work if the ejb bean is a stateless bean and also annotated with the CDI annotation ```@Dependent```

Comment: @maress Are you sure? I've checked it - this does not work (one instance is injected twice). It makes no sense because usually stateless beans are pooled and are not initialized when reused. OP wants some initialization before injection.